# How can I add this condition?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, operators, backend

```php
$test1 = 7;
$test2 = 1;
$test3 = 3;
$total = $test1 + $test2 + $test3;

$isPassed = ( $total >= 10 && $test >= 2 ) ? true : false;

echo ( $isPassed ) ? "Passed" : "Not Passed";
```

[Variable $**test**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK479.png)

I want to make that *second condition* is such that a student cannot pass the exam if on one of these tests he gets a grade that is lower than or equal to number 2.
How can I code that?

Comment: `$isPassed = ( $total >= 10 && $test1 >= 2 && $test2 >= 2 && $test3 >= 2 ) ? true : false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add them all to an array then use `min()`.

```
//preferably store all of the test scores in an array
//instead of a separate variable for each one.
$test_scores = [$test1, $test2, $test3];

$total = array_sum($test_scores);

//you don't need the ternary because this expression will
//return true/false anyways
$isPassed = ($total >= 10 && min($test_scores) > 2);
```

Comment: nice usage of `array_sum`